# How to validate a response and extract a value from Response body in Rest Assured?

Tags: java, rest-assured

I know how to extract a value from Response body and also how to validate a field from response body, but what the problem is

```
void postRequest() {
    Response id = given()
            .auth()
            .preemptive()
            .basic(username,password)
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .body(----- some JSON body ------)
            .when()
            .post(baseurl+"postRequest")
            .then()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .extract()
            .path("id")
            ;
}
```

with this, I can extract the value that I want to and saved it into a variable "id" and use it for further API requests.

```
response
    .then()
    .log().ifValidationFails(LogDetail.ALL, true)  # I NEED TO PRINT REQUEST PARAMS TOO IF IT FAILS
    .assertThat()
    .statusCode(200)
    ;
```

If I did the above approach, I couldn't get to validate the response body since we didn't save the response to a variable.

I want to do both in one go. Also, I tried the opposite too, where I validated the response body first, but I couldn't save the "id" since we can't convert ValidatableResponse to Response or vice versa. I do not want to print the request params unless the request fails.

Help me find a way with this.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you want both: validate response and extract value (for other API) in one chain command. This is example:

```
int id = given().post()
        .then()
        .log().ifValidationFails()
        .assertThat()
        .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .statusCode(200)
        .body("id", equalTo("test"))
        .extract()
        .response()
        .path("id");
```

Comment: This approach doesn't throw any error, but the problem is when the assertion fails, it no longer extracts the value from the response. I don't know why this happens.

Comment: `This approach doesn't throw any error` --> are you sure about it?
`it no longer extracts the value from the response` --> it make sense, it throws error when assert fails --> this test fails --> no need any action after that.

Comment: I mentioned syntax errors. Yeah, that's the problem I'm facing.  I tried to extract it first and if tried to assert after that, I get syntax error.

Comment: Of course, this approach makes no compile error, it was born to do that function. https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#extracting-values-from-the-response-after-validation No, you cannot extract first, then assert in one chain command. You have to break it to 2 different commands.